# current_date IN PROCEDURE sNOWFLAKE

Tags: javascript, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC_XXGSI_AR_ACCOUNT_DETAILS_V()
returns string not null
language javascript
as
$$
var cmd = "SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM  staging_xxgsi_ar_account_details_v" ;
var cmd1=  "DELETE FROM xxgsi_ar_account_details_v WHERE invoice_date>= "+ DATEADD(Day ,-30, 
          current_date) ;
var sql = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: cmd});
var result = sql.execute();

while (result.next())  {
       var column1 = result.getColumnValue(1)

if (column1 > 0) 
{ 
var sql1 = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: cmd1});
var result1 = sql1.execute();
}
}
return 'A';
$$;
```

There is a space in column "invoice date" and its not invoice_date. How I can tackle it ?

Comment: Thanks . Do you know how i can handle space in column name in the select statement?

Comment: Surround your column name in double quotes to include spaces, but the caveat is that as soon as you introduce double quotes the column name will also be case sensitive so you have to be exact.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for string concatenation:

```
var cmd1="DELETE FROM xxgsi_ar_account_details_v WHERE invoice_date>= "+ DATEADD(Day ,-30, 
          current_date) ;
```

It should be:

```
var cmd1=`DELETE FROM xxgsi_ar_account_details_v WHERE "invoice date">= DATEADD(Day,-30, current_date)`
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how I can handle blank space in column name. The invoice_date is actually invoice date in the table.

Comment: If you have special characters in column/table name then quote idenfitied with `"`: `"invoice date"` (case sensitive)

Comment: can you please answer with the whole select statement. Sorry I am not clear yet. Thank you

Comment: @Chints `DELETE FROM xxgsi_ar_account_details_v WHERE "invoice date">= DATEADD(Day,-30, current_date)`.

Comment: Thanks. It failed with below message [FATAL] The Snowflake Connector failed to initialize the read operation because of the following error: JavaScript compilation error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in PROC_XXGSI_AR_ACCOUNT_DETAILS_V at 'var cmd1= DELETE FROM xxgsi_ar_account_details_v WHERE "invoice date" >= DATEADD(Day ,-30, current_date) ;' position 18